# How do I deal with having different environments but same images in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I have two different sites, a development site, and a staging site, with the same Shopify theme. I also have my theme files on git. I merge my development branch to my staging branch but I get a lot of conflicts with image paths.

For example, some CSS code will conflict
staging:`background: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0553/6117/5731/t/44/assets/contact_bg_img.png?29198)`

development:`background: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0196/8186/9924/t/70/assets/contact_bg_img.png?36011)`

The images are the same it's just that the location changes because they're different stores. If I merge the changes then the image location will be incorrect.
I'm not sure how to deal with this issue. Has anyone dealt with this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to treat these images as [theme assets](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture#supporting-assets). You can add these images to your assets directory in theme and then use [URL filters](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/url-filters#asset_img_url) to generate the URL for the images.

```
{{ 'contact_bg_img.png' | asset_img_url: '300x' }}
```

If you want to use your current solution, like uploading files and then use that URL, this can also be done via [URL filters](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/url-filters#file_img_url).

```
{{ 'contact_bg_img.png' | file_img_url: '1024x768' }}
```

Doing so, you will have the same code for multiple stores and no hardcoded URLs inside code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload the Image in `Settings -> Files` at any store(Staging or Development).